# Angular multiple ajax calls on same controller sometimes not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've just started using Angular with Ionic and so far it's great except for a problem with my ecommerce app where I am doing two ajax requests, one to load the vendor name and the other to load the products. I know I could put this in the same request but for other reasons it needs to  be kept it separate.

Sometimes the vendor name gets set and sometimes it fails. It seems to be completely random and if I put a debugger in place it always works so appears to be something to do with timing.

```
.controller('VendorProductsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {

  var vendor_name_url = 'URL FOR VENDOR NAME';

  $http.get(vendor_name_url)
    .success(function(response){
      $scope.vendor_name = response.meta.vendor_name;
      //debugger; this always works!
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      console.log('server error');
    })

  $scope.products = [];

  $scope.loadMore = function() {

    var url = 'URL FOR PRODUCTS';

    $http.get(url)
      .success(function(response){
        $scope.products = response.products;
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        console.log('server error');
      })
  };
})
```

There seems to be something fundamental that I am missing on my new quest into Angular land. Thanks for your help.

P.S I'm using Ionic's infinite scroll which is calling loadMore()

**Got it working, but seems a bit dodgy!**

```
  setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.vendor_name = response.meta.vendor_name;
    });
  }, 500);
```

I'm not keen on waiting for 500ms or whatever it's set to if it's ready earlier, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with the http request for the vendor name being finished before the `$scope` is applied when it works.

Move the definition of your `$scope.vendor_name` outside of the promise callback.

```js
$scope.vendor_name = '';

$http.get(vendor_name_url).success(function(response){
    $scope.vendor_name = response.meta.vendor_name;
})
.error(function(data) {
  console.log('server error');
});
```

`loadMore()` works correctly because the `$scope` has the variable of `products = [];` during the wire-up of the controller. Everything after that hits the scope lifecycle of updating.

**EDIT:**

I would try to avoid doing the `$scope.$apply` function as you will then start using it everywhere and it makes the maintenance of your services and controllers very difficult.

Another way to approach this issue is to use resolves on your route.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

This is a great approach to getting multiple data pieces into your controller defined by the route. The wire-up of the controller by the route is responsible for ensuring that data is available for dependency injection on the controller when it runs.

Comment: Thanks for this, I gave it a try and it doesn't seem to make any difference. See my edit in the question above as I have a working solution but I'm not sure if it's the proper way!

Comment: Hey @sebastyuiop. I've updated my answer, see if an approach like that can be used in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

```
$q.all([
    $http.get(vendor_name_url),
    $http.get(url)
]).then(function(_responses){
    $scope.vendor_name = _responses[0].meta.vendor_name;
    $scope.products = _responses[1].products;
})
```

Comment: I am not sure that _response[X] or _response[X].data, double check before you use. @sebastyuiop

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the right way to do it. I'm having trouble getting it to fit with my code though as the request to get more products is in the loadMore() function and the request for the vendor name sits outside of it. Do you think I should split it in to two controllers?

Comment: @sebastyuiop, personally, I won't split it to two controllers, since products and vendor name will need it in same page. writing some service would work, but that would trigger timing issues again. Actually, in my company private project, I combined all needed http requests in server side and feed it as single jsonp to initial page load though.